# Optimization of primary key uid : same length longer CHAR Vs. different length shorter VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (> 100k rows) that contains data imported from two different APIs. As a consequence, UID from each API have a significantly different length (35 from the first API and 19 from the second). These UIDs are alphabenumerical strings (`AMANR5L16PO791932BTC0014P0D1N000001` for the 1st API and `AMSNT006654N00II598` for the 2nd).

These UIDs are the primary key of my table.

I wonder what's the best in term of performance between having a primary key with a length up to 35 stored as `VARCHAR(35)` and having a primary key with an uniformized length of 35 (by adding "XXX" to the end of the shortest UIDs in order to have only UIDs with a length of 35) to store them as `CHAR(35)`.

Comment: No difference. I'd recommend VARCHAR - in this case you shouldn't use additional padding/trimming in your queries.

Comment: Performance of what?

If you're concerned about performance, you would have to test a specific query. You haven't shown any queries you're concerned about.

Comment: This could make sense in an "extreme performance optimization" scenario only. For 100k rows this optimization doesn't make sense. For 100 billion rows, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pad.  Not even for 100 billion rows.  `VARCHAR` will store only the actual data (plus a length).  Shrinking space also provides some performance.  But neither is worth sneezing at.